# Prove that $f^*(x)\geq \frac{c}{\|x\|^n}$ if $f$ integrable.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $f:\mathbb R^n\longrightarrow \mathbb R$ a non-zera integrable function. Set $$f^*(x)\geq \sup_{B\ni x}\frac{1}{|B|}\int_B f(y)\mathrm d y,$$
where the supremum is taken over all the ball that contain $x$. How can I prove that there is a $c>0$ s.t. $$f^*(x)\geq \frac{c}{\|x\|^n}\ \ ?$$
I really have no idea.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\|x\|\geq 1$. Your definition is wrong. $$Mf(x)=\sup_{B\ni x}\frac{1}{|B|}\int_B|f(y)|dy.$$ Then, $$Mf(x)\geq \frac{1}{|B(x,2\|x\|)|}\int_{B(x,2\|x\|)}|f(y)|dy=\frac{1}{V_n2^n\|x\|^n}\int_{B(x,2\|x\|)}|f(y)|dy$$
$$\geq \frac{1}{V_n2^n\|x\|^n}\int_{B(0,1)}|f(y)|dy,$$
where $V_n=|B(0,1)|$, what prove the claim.